# How to use alternative JSON lib from Spring MVC

Tags: java, spring-mvc, jackson, flexjson

My understanding is that Spring MVC ships with a version/dependency of the [Jackson JSON](http://jackson.codehaus.org/) library. I really like/prefer FlexJSON and was wondering if it is possible to configure Spring to use [FlexJSON](http://flexjson.sourceforge.net/) instead, and if so, how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Spring uses the `HttpMessageConverter` to generate a response when you annotate your handle method with `@ResponseBody` or when you return a `ResponseEntity` object.

When Spring sets up your MVC configuration, it registers a number of `HttpMessageConverter` implementations, among which is the `Jackson` implementation, `MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter`. It does this in the `WebMvcConfigurationSupport` class (Spring MVC 3.1+)

```
@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
protected final void addDefaultHttpMessageConverters(List<HttpMessageConverter<?>> messageConverters) {
    StringHttpMessageConverter stringConverter = new StringHttpMessageConverter();
    stringConverter.setWriteAcceptCharset(false);

    messageConverters.add(new ByteArrayHttpMessageConverter());
    messageConverters.add(stringConverter);
    messageConverters.add(new ResourceHttpMessageConverter());
    messageConverters.add(new SourceHttpMessageConverter<Source>());
    messageConverters.add(new AllEncompassingFormHttpMessageConverter());
    if (romePresent) {
        messageConverters.add(new AtomFeedHttpMessageConverter());
        messageConverters.add(new RssChannelHttpMessageConverter());
    }
    if (jaxb2Present) {
        messageConverters.add(new Jaxb2RootElementHttpMessageConverter());
    }
    if (jackson2Present) {
        messageConverters.add(new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter());
    }
    else if (jacksonPresent) {
        messageConverters.add(new org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter());
    }
}
```

These are registered as defaults. Before doing this, Spring registers any custom `HttpMessageConverter` bean or instances you might want.

So the solution is to implement your own with `flexjson` and register it. Registering depends on what kind of configuration you are doing, but there are resources out there for each.